# Error with Exception handling try....except with 3 possible cases

Tags: python, exception

I am doing web scraping.
I need to extract a data field (typo) and I have 3 possible cases:

```
try:
#1st case
typo = int(response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Chambres")]/following- 
sibling::td[@class="right"]/text()').extract()[0])                       
except: 
#2nd case when the 1st case gives an IndexError    
typo = int(sel1.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Pièces (nombre total)")]/following-sibling::td[@class="right"]/text()').extract()[0])
except IndexError: 
#3rd case, when the first and second case give IndexError       
typo = 0
```

I have an execution error (except must be the last)

Comment: I added some comments to the code. please take a look.

Comment: Don't use a bare `except` clause; at the very least, use `except Exception` to avoid catching things like `SystemExit` that you almost certainly do not want to catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want nested `try` statements:

```
try:
    x = response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Chambres")]/following-sibling::td[@class="right"]/text()')
    typo = int(x.extract()[0])
except IndexError:
    try:
        x = sel1.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Pièces (nombre total)")]/following-sibling::td[@class="right"]/text()')
        typo = int(x.extract()[0])
    except IndexError:
        typo = 0
```

You might use a loop to simplify this a little:

```
attempts = [
    (response.xpath, '//td...'),
    (sel1.xpath, '/td...'),
]
typo = 0
for f, arg in attempts:
    try:
        typo = int(f(arg).extract()[0])
    except IndexError:
        continue
```

`typo` is initialized to the fallback value, but will be overwritten if either attempted parse succeeds.